# How do I set Django to use Python 2.7 instead of Python 2.4?

Tags: python, django

I have installed Python 2.7 but still kept Python 2.4. When I enter the command `python`, it runs python 2.4 and I want to keep it this way. But how to I set Django to use `/usr/local/bin/python2.7` when it runs?

[EDIT]
It is running on Apache with WSGI

Comment: What web server are you running it in, and how is it configured?

Answer (score 2):

Since you use WSGI, you should compile WSGI with a compile-flag to choose which python-version to use:

```
./configure --with-python=/usr/local/bin/python2.7
```

See here: http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/InstallationIssues#Multiple_Python_Versions

Comment: Also make sure you reinstall any required packages using the new python version.